# SAML, and forcing a re-authentication

Tags: passwords, sso, saml

I have a use case forced upon me by industry regulation. I wish it wasn't there, but it is.

A user logs in to my service, navigates around, etc. The user can perform many actions, but one of the actions **requires** (by industry regulation) that the user re-enter the username and password prior to continuing. It does not matter if the user logged in 5 seconds beforehand. In order to complete this action the user **must** re-enter the username and password.

We are looking to integrate with another company, using SAML to power SSO and Federated IDs. Is there a way for us to tell the IdP to re-authenticate the user, even if the user is already authenticated?

Thanks
Alan

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For SAML 2.0 identity providers that support it you can pass [`ForceAuthn="true"`](http://www.schemacentral.com/sc/saml2/e-samlp_AuthnRequest.html) as an attribute for the AuthnRequest. This will tell the IdP to not use any previous security context when authenticating the user.